# Laravel - Vue - The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel, vue.js

tengo este const que me recibe los datos del formulario:

```
export const deleteUser = ({ dispatch }, payload) => {
    console.log("El numero de id es js: ", payload.id);
    return axios
        .delete(window.urls.user.delete(payload.id))
        .then(respone => {
            dispatch("fetchUsers");
            return Promise.resolve();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
};
```

esto es lo que tengo en mi api.php que convoca el axios para enviar el id del registro a borrar:

```
Route::delete('/{user}', [
            'uses' => 'UserController@destroy',
            'middleware' => 'permission:user.delete',
            'can:delete,user'    
        ]);
```

esto es lo que tengo en mi config.blade.php

```
user: {
            index : '/user',
            store: '/user',
            update: function(userid){
                return '/user/' + userid
            },
            delete: function(id){
                return '/user/' + id;
            }
        },
```

este es codigo de mi controlador:

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user=User::find($id);
        $user->delete();
    }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor agregar tu formulario?

Comment: Bueno hay veces en que la gente pregunta y no pone código. Tú pusiste más código que pregunta. Esto ha pasado desde siempre o alguna vez funcionó?

Comment: ya hice los controles en el formulario y si los envia a los datos correctamente al const que se encuentra en el js. Aun asi lo necesitas que agregue el formulario?

Comment: amenadiel tengo un controller que funciona bien y es exacmente igual a este desde el js hasta el controlador, simplemente hice copia y modifique los datos necesarios

Comment: Sé que alguna vez me pasó y no recuerdo si era culpa del CSRF Token o el caché de Laravel. Qué rutas tienes listadas en `php artisan  route:list`?

Comment: me aparece esta ruta en la lista: DELETE | api/user/user/{user} | | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@destroy | api,auth:api,permission:user.delete